# Use 'async' and 'await' in VB.net without return needed

Tags: vb.net, async-await

I have a web application and need copy a batch of files from one file share server to another after a button click, async and awit seems to be a good way for this.
I am not sure do I need Task.Run here? Is RunMoving() better move into another class for performance?

Here is my VB.NET code as following:

```
Public Sub FileMoving()
    PdfsMovingAsync()
    DoSomethingElse()
End Sub

Private Async Sub PdfsMovingAsync()
    Await Task.Run(Sub() RunMoving())
End Sub

Private Sub RunMoving()
    'Thread.Sleep(2000)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PdfsMovingAsync` should return `Task`. You want to avoid Async Subs.

Since `DoSomethingElse` is not dependent on `PdfsMovingAsync` completing first then they can run simultaneously.

```
Public Sub FileMoving()
    PdfsMovingAsync()
    DoSomethingElse()
End Sub

Private Function PdfsMovingAsync() As Task
    Return Task.Run(Sub() RunMoving())
End Function
```

`Await` should ideally be used to actually await a function if something is dependent on it finishing first.

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: `Private Function ... End Sub` I guess that's a typo?